# Liquid If statement does not run else

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am trying to set class"price" two different types of data depending on if the IF statement is true/false, the If statement does the first part but if the else is true class"price" does not set the variable, anybody know why?

```
{% if dynamic_products.compare_at_price_max > dynamic_products.price %}
                <p class="old-price"><span class="price-sep"></span><span class="price">Box 
Value:{{ dynamic_products.compare_at_price | money }}</span></p>                  
                
                {% else %}
                <p class="old-price"><span class="price-sep"></span><span class="price">{{ 
'products.product.sold_out_html' | t }}</span></p>
                {% endif %}
```

Comment: can you please share the frontend page URL with example, what you really want to do?

Comment: dynamic_products is not a regular object in Shopify so I'd like to understand what it's and what is its value. I think you have the problem on dynamic_products.compare_at_price_max

Comment: @MichelArteta the problem is everything works out side of this function, so either the function is not laid out correctly inn terms of syntax or there is a problem with setting class="price" with the else.

Comment: We can get some debugging info printed to the page if you print the variables you want to compare by running them through the `json` filter first - this helps us figure out if we're comparing the values we think we're comparing. For example, before your `{% if ... %}` statement, we could add `<h2> {{ dynamic_products.compare_at_price_max | json }} | {{ dynamic_products.price | json }} </h2>`

Comment: The `json` filter makes any output Javascript-legal, which means that it has some cool features for debugging purposes - text will be wrapped in quotation marks while numbers won't be, so that will tell us if we're accidentally comparing things alphabetically rather than numerically. Empty values will be printed as `null`, which tells us that we're not actually getting the variables we're expecting, ect.  If our debugging output is **null | null** for example, that will tell us that the variable `dynamic_products` isn't a single product.